# Tensorflow Convolution Neural Network with different sized images

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, deconvolution

I am attempting to create a deep CNN that can classify each individual pixel in an image. I am replicating architecture from the image below taken from [this](https://github.com/dhasl002/Research-DeepLearning/blob/master/DEEP.pdf) paper. In the paper it is mentioned that deconvolutions are used so that any size of input is possible. This can be seen in the image below.

[Github Repository](https://github.com/dhasl002/Research-DeepLearning)

[image]

Currently, I have hard coded my model to accept images of size 32x32x7, but I would like to accept any size of input. **What changes would I need to make to my code to accept variable sized input?**

```
 x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32*32*7])
 y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32*32*7, 3])
 ...
 DeConnv1 = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(layer1, filter = w, output_shape = [1,32,32,7,1], strides = [1,2,2,2,1], padding = 'SAME')
 ...
 final = tf.reshape(final, [1, 32*32*7])
 W_final = weight_variable([32*32*7,32*32*7,3])
 b_final = bias_variable([32*32*7,3])
 final_conv = tf.tensordot(final, W_final, axes=[[1], [1]]) + b_final
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Dynamic placeholders

Tensorflow allows to have *multiple* dynamic (a.k.a. `None`) dimensions in placeholders. The engine won't be able to ensure correctness while the graph is built, hence the client is responsible for feeding the correct input, but it provides a lot of flexibility.

So I'm going from...

```py
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, N*M*P])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, N*M*P, 3])
...
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, N, M, P, 1])
```

to...

```py
# Nearly all dimensions are dynamic
x_image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, None, None, 1])
label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, 3])
```

Since you intend to reshape the input to 5D anyway, so why don't use 5D in `x_image` right from the start. At this point, the second dimension of `label` is arbitrary, but we *promise* tensorflow that it will match with `x_image`.

### Dynamic shapes in deconvolution

Next, the nice thing about [`tf.nn.conv3d_transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv3d_transpose) is that its output shape can be dynamic. So instead of this:

```py
# Hard-coded output shape
DeConnv1 = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(layer1, w, output_shape=[1,32,32,7,1], ...)
```

... you can do this:

```py
# Dynamic output shape
DeConnv1 = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(layer1, w, output_shape=tf.shape(x_image), ...)
```

This way the transpose convolution can be applied to *any* image and the result will take the shape of `x_image` that was actually passed in at runtime.

Note that static shape of `x_image` is `(?, ?, ?, ?, 1)`.

### All-Convolutional network

Final and most important piece of the puzzle is to make **the whole network** convolutional, and that includes your final dense layer too. Dense layer *must* define its dimensions statically, which forces the whole neural network fix input image dimensions.

Luckily for us, Springenberg at al describe a way to replace an FC layer with a CONV layer in ["Striving for Simplicity: The All Convolutional Net"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6806) paper. I'm going to use a convolution with 3 `1x1x1` filters (see also [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/194142/130598)):

```py
final_conv = conv3d_s1(final, weight_variable([1, 1, 1, 1, 3]))
y = tf.reshape(final_conv, [-1, 3])
```

If we ensure that `final` has the same dimensions as `DeConnv1` (and others), it'll make `y` right the shape we want: `[-1, N * M * P, 3]`.

### Combining it all together

Your network is pretty large, but all deconvolutions basically follow the same pattern, so I've simplified my *proof-of-concept* code to just one deconvolution. The goal is just to show what kind of network is able to handle images of arbitrary size. Final remark: image dimensions can vary *between* batches, but within one batch they have to be the same.

The full code:

```py
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

def conv3d_dilation(tempX, tempFilter):
  return tf.layers.conv3d(tempX, filters=tempFilter, kernel_size=[3, 3, 1], strides=1, padding='SAME', dilation_rate=2)

def conv3d(tempX, tempW):
  return tf.nn.conv3d(tempX, tempW, strides=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

def conv3d_s1(tempX, tempW):
  return tf.nn.conv3d(tempX, tempW, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def max_pool_3x3(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool3d(x, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

x_image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, None, None, 1])
label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, 3])

W_conv1 = weight_variable([3, 3, 1, 1, 32])
h_conv1 = conv3d(x_image, W_conv1)
# second convolution
W_conv2 = weight_variable([3, 3, 4, 32, 64])
h_conv2 = conv3d_s1(h_conv1, W_conv2)
# third convolution path 1
W_conv3_A = weight_variable([1, 1, 1, 64, 64])
h_conv3_A = conv3d_s1(h_conv2, W_conv3_A)
# third convolution path 2
W_conv3_B = weight_variable([1, 1, 1, 64, 64])
h_conv3_B = conv3d_s1(h_conv2, W_conv3_B)
# fourth convolution path 1
W_conv4_A = weight_variable([3, 3, 1, 64, 96])
h_conv4_A = conv3d_s1(h_conv3_A, W_conv4_A)
# fourth convolution path 2
W_conv4_B = weight_variable([1, 7, 1, 64, 64])
h_conv4_B = conv3d_s1(h_conv3_B, W_conv4_B)
# fifth convolution path 2
W_conv5_B = weight_variable([1, 7, 1, 64, 64])
h_conv5_B = conv3d_s1(h_conv4_B, W_conv5_B)
# sixth convolution path 2
W_conv6_B = weight_variable([3, 3, 1, 64, 96])
h_conv6_B = conv3d_s1(h_conv5_B, W_conv6_B)
# concatenation
layer1 = tf.concat([h_conv4_A, h_conv6_B], 4)
w = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1., shape=[2, 2, 4, 1, 192]))
DeConnv1 = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(layer1, filter=w, output_shape=tf.shape(x_image), strides=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

final = DeConnv1
final_conv = conv3d_s1(final, weight_variable([1, 1, 1, 1, 3]))
y = tf.reshape(final_conv, [-1, 3])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=label, logits=y))

print('x_image:', x_image)
print('DeConnv1:', DeConnv1)
print('final_conv:', final_conv)

def try_image(N, M, P, B=1):
  batch_x = np.random.normal(size=[B, N, M, P, 1])
  batch_y = np.ones([B, N * M * P, 3]) / 3.0

  deconv_val, final_conv_val, loss = sess.run([DeConnv1, final_conv, cross_entropy],
                                              feed_dict={x_image: batch_x, label: batch_y})
  print(deconv_val.shape)
  print(final_conv.shape)
  print(loss)
  print()

tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
try_image(32, 32, 7)
try_image(16, 16, 3)
try_image(16, 16, 3, 2)
```

Comment: I could never get this solution to work. Every part of the answer worked except the "All-Convolutional network" section. First of all, I do not believe that is a dense layer. When I use your solution for that section, I get an incompatible shapes error.

Comment: No error for tf 1.5. The code in the answer is almost complete, only imports are missing. And `try_image` works for me. Also I never said it is a dense layer. It is a *replacement* of a dense layer

Comment: I am sorry to question your answer. For anyone reading, this did actually work. Thank you.

Comment: @DevinHaslam sorry for delay, I missed the previous discussion. What was the issue?

Comment: The 1x1x1x1x3 convolution causes some problems. One of the three weights in that convolution will always be too small for that class to be predicted. Please take a look at this image that demonstrates the problem: https://imgur.com/a/OjDRB

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically, it's possible. you need to set the image size of the input and label image place holder to `none`, and let the graph dynamically infer the image size from input data.

However, have to be careful when you define the graph. Need to use `tf.shape` instead of `tf.get_shape()`. the former dynamically infer the shape only when you `session.run`, the latter can get the shape when you define the graph. But when input size is set to `none`, the latter does not get true reshape (maybe just return None).

And to make things complicated, if you use `tf.layers.conv2d` or `upconv2d`, sometimes these high level functions do not like `tf.shape`, because it seems they assume the shape information are available during graph construction.

I hope I have better working example to show the points above. I'll put this answer as a placeholder and will come back and add more stuff if I get a chance.